# The night of stark awakening

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

**`The night of stark awakening`** is this a phrase or any kind of common saying?

I want know the meaning of- **stark awakening**

I found some meaning of the word **Stark** -

- Empty
- Simple
- Obvious
- Completely

But I was unable to put any of these defining word before the word `awakening`

Comment: Is there any context to this that you can include?

Comment: [Try a different dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stark)  *severe or unmitigated; harsh or grim*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess with the bare context:

**[stark](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stark)** as in *completely* (entry 2).

Completely awake is juxtaposed with "night," where one should be... completely asleep.

Note that **[awakening](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awakening)** carries with it a sense of being enlightened beyond merely being roused from slumber.

So, the phrase as a whole could refer to an evening during which one was made wholly aware of a situation.

Comment: I would suggest meaning 4.b.2 under your link **Harsh or blunt**. When one wakes in the night there is sometimes a feeling of coming face to face with the horrible reality of something we have been trying not to think about.

Comment: The examples presented by the OP don't encompass the full definitions of stark, as delineated by Jim and Ben. In this context, stark most likely means an abrupt/rude awakening that leads to a complete awakening, due to a fight or flight response. The comments by Jim and Ben, along with the answer by Carly, most likely represent the true meaning of the sentence.